# Polar decomposition on $\mathbf{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: representation-theory, general-linear-group

I am asked to prove that for $g\in\mathbf{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, $g$ can be unique written as $$g=k_1
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & & 0\\
    & \ddots &\\
    0 & & a_n
    \end{pmatrix}
    k_2, k_1,k_2\in\mathbf{O}(n,\mathbb{R}), a_1\geq a_2\geq\dots\geq a_n>0$$.

I think this is somehow related to the polar decomposition mentioned in Axler's linear algebra done right, however I have no exact idea how to do it concisely. Any help or recommended reading?

Comment: This is singular value decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: @Endpoints If you want to start with the polar decomposition, then simply use the fact that the positive definite transformation $P$ in the product $g = UP$ can be diagonalized

Answer (score 2):

The factorization in question is a special case of the matrix version of the singular value decomposition. See Theorem 7.77 in the forthcoming fourth edition of *Linear Algebra Done Right*. Chapter 7 of this forthcoming new edition is freely available at https://linear.axler.net/.